# Hardhat timeout settings not respected

Tags: hardhat, moralis

Tried various RPCs when deploying a series of contracts to Rinkeby and Kovan - infura, moralis, alchemy, while setting large timeout settings on Hardhat, but keep running into the same issue:

```
hijackedStack: 'Error: Failed to check for transaction receipt:\n' + '{\n' + ' "data": {\n' + ' "stack": 

"FetchError: request to https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/XXX failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.85.169.91:443\\n at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/xxx/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1491:11)\\n at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)\\n at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:461:9)\\n at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)\\n at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:96:8)\\n at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:3)\\n at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)",\n' + ' "name": "FetchError"\n' + ' }

\n' + '}\n' + ' at Object._fireError (/xxx/node_modules/web3-core-method/node_modules/web3-utils/lib/index.js:50:17)\n' + ' at /xxx/node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:243:23'
```

Hardhat.config.js:

```
rinkeby: {
       url: infuraRinkeby2(),
       gas: 10000000, // tx gas limit
      timeout: 10000000,
      networkCheckTimeout: 1000000,
      timeoutBlocks: 30000,
      skipDryRun: true,
      confirmations: 10,
      accounts: [      ],
```

Tried various timeout settings in hardhat configs, but keep getting the above error at various stages of deploying my contracts - sometimes after 3 or 5 of them, sometimes after 10 or 12... As the total contract package is about 20 and the later ones need addresses of the previous ones when deploying, it becomes a bit of a minefield if the connections keeps dropping like this...

Any ideas why hardhat doesn't respect the timeout settings and how to keep the connection alive for enough time to deploy a combination of contracts?

Comment: i face the same issue. i cannot override the default timeout using hardhat 2.8.2. my test sometimes pass and sometimes timeout to default 40000ms using Rinkeby testnet